How does Aurora Postgresql Global database work for writes requests from multiple regions?
I have a single Aurora Postgresql serverless v2 cluster in AWS in one region. I am planning to deploy it to multiple regions by using global database. After some reading, I found in multiple regions cluster, it can only have one primary region which can take write requests. Multiple regions seems only benefits on read.
Let's say, I have two regions, one in US, the other is in EU, and if I pick the EU region as primary one, all the requests from US will have to call the endpoint in EU region for updating data. It will make the performance in US very bad.
How should I support multiple regions in Aurora postgresql? Do I miss anything?

You cannot do that, unless you shard your data: split the database in two parts, one that is predominantly used by the US and one that is mostly used by the EU. Each database gets some foreign tables to transparently access the other's data. Ideally, you partition your tables based on US/EU, then you can use the foreign table as a partition.
Tables that are small and common to both reside only on one of the databases. You could use a foreign table or logical replication to make these data available on both sides.

Does the Aurora cluster supports shard? or do I have to implement the shard key in my application?

Using partitioning as I outlined, each query would have to add WHERE region = 'EU' to access only the local data, if you want good performance. So the application would have to play along.

So Aurora cluster doesn't support it automatically? I will have to implement the sharding logic in my application?

@JoeyYiZhao Yep.

Hi @LaurenzAlbe Is there a doc or a blog that describes how to implement this solution?
